# adding proprietary transport for sunrpc

Tags: rpc, sunrpc

I am trying to implement a RPC mechanism in an embedded SoC. The SoC has a dual-core cortexA9, with one core running ThreadX and the other running Linux 3.8.

My question is:

1. Is Sunrpc a good choice for this?
2. As far as I know, sunrpc on Linux only supports UDP/TCP transport. Is it possible to add a proprietary transport? Is so, do I have to hack both user-space and kernel code?

Thanks
Joey

Comment: Msgpack maybe? Sunrpc has a lot of cruft and is difficult to use securely (requiring AUTH_DES which is non-trivial)

Comment: Also porting sunrpc to another stream or datagram protocol wouldn’t be terribly difficult but it’s not worth the effort because I think sunrpc (pedantically, ONCRPC) is not the right choice)